# How to override FileField and automatically delete previous file in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, overriding, uploading

im django beginner (django 1.2.5)
I have that model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #other fields
    #other fields
```

and model form to this:

```
class DocumentForm(ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField(required=True, error_messages={'required' : 'required!','empty': "empty!"})
    title = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 93,}), error_messages={'required': 'required!'})
   #other fields
   #other fields
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        exclude = ('author',)
def save(self, author, commit=True):
    document=ModelForm.save(self,commit=False)
    document.author = author
    if commit:
        document.save()
    return document
```

I uploading new documents in using DocumentForm above and it works pretty but when i trying edit some document i cannot put new file in place previous. I may change every field except FileField.

```
def document_edit(request, document_id):
    doc = get_object_or_404(Document, id=document_id)
    form = DocumentForm(instance=doc)
    if doc.author == request.user:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=doc)
            if form.is_valid():
                if request.POST.get('cancel'):
                   return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
                elif request.POST.get('delete'):
                    document = Document.objects.get(id=document_id)
                    document.file.delete()
                    document.delete()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
                else:
                    form.save(author=request.user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                # return again form with errors
        else:
            # return form with doc instance
    else:
        # return "you can't edit this doc!"
```

I research django documentation and i only know i should write some custom save method in some class but i completely have no idea how can i do this. It should be save() method in Document() or in DocumentForm()?
Generally i want this: When i put path to new file in form i want override this new file in his place and automatically delete previous file.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, you just want to use the `instance` keyword, so your form reflects the object being edited. Simplified version:

```
def edit_upload(request, document_id):
    doc = get_object_or_404(Document, id=document_id)
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=doc)
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            if doc.file: # If document has file already...
                doc.file.delete() # delete it
            form.save() # Saves object, uses new uploaded file
            return redirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after success
    else:
        form = DocumentForm(instance=doc) # Show form to edit

    return render(request, 'edit.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Comment: But i just want delete existed file. This form is for upload new file. Why form.save() dont saving new file?

Comment: Still nothing! form saving everything except file. I forgot previously about DocumentForm method that i have added. Mayby this is problem:     def save(self, author, commit=True):

        document=ModelForm.save(self,commit=False)

        document.author = author

        if commit:

            document.save()

        return document